# Can't execute Maven Project: Tomcat freezes starting ProtocolHandler

Tags: maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I've created a Maven web project, which is to run on tomcat7. When I start the tomcat server manually and execute commands `mvn clean install`, `mvn tomcat7:deploy` everything goes well, the application is deployed and I can access it. But if I don't run tomcat manually and try to execute `mvn tomcat7:run`, the tomcat server won't start. It freezes on starting `ProtocolHandler`.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace, please?